# SDL-2.0 library not working with codeblocks-13.12-mingw-tdm

Tags: c++, sdl

I started following lazyfoo's sdl 2.0 tutorials. This is the very first tutorial that explains how to set up SDL 2.0 with code::blocks - [SDL 2.0 with code::blocks setup](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php). I am doing exactly what it says but still getting this error:-

```
|121|fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory|
    ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the code that I tried to run. I copied and pasted exactly as it is given in the source code for the tutorial :-

```
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2015)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22446008/2038264